# Integrate one electron project into another with webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, electron, ipc

I have a large electron nodejs project. I also have another project with functionality that I would like to include in the initial project.

I'm trying to find the most effective way to include the second project within the first project. The two projects do not need to interact with each other. The second project should be launched when triggered by IPC.

When in development mode, I can do this as follows:

```js
app.on('launch-project2', async () => {

      exec("cd project2/ && npm start", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
          return;
        } else if (stderr) {
          console.log(stderr);
          return;
        } else if (stdout) {
          console.log(stdout);
        }
      });
})
```

Is it possible to perform this same functionality after the project is compiled in webpack?

Comment: Can both projects use the same webpack config with different entry points? If so then you could create a new renderer window from the base app.

Comment: @CUGreen would you have an example implementation with the multiple entry points and new renderer window?